# Adding strings to a list via for loop xna

Tags: c#, string, list, for-loop, xna

So, I need 300 strings (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc, etc) And I've decided to use a for loop to add them to my list, but it keeps giving me errors no matter what I try and I'm very confused right now. This is what I currently have:

```
 int stringcount = 0;
 List<string> ButtonStrings;
 ButtonStrings = new List<string>();
 for (int i = 0; i < 299; i++)
        {
            stringcount += 1;
            ButtonStrings.Add(stringcount.ToString);
        }
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis after `ToString()`.

Comment: Well I made a stupid mistake, thank you for telling me!

Comment: Try to see the `ErrorBox` and read the error carefully. Visual Studio is pretty smart in catching typo errors.

Comment: Just as a minor point of style, unrelated to the error, your ```i``` variable is not being used in the loop.                                                       ```for (stringcount = 1; stringcount < 300; ++stringcount)``` would be cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having `stringcount.ToString`, which is a method group, you need to call this method by adding parenthesis `()`. Change

```
ButtonStrings.Add(stringcount.ToString);
```

to

```
ButtonStrings.Add(stringcount.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

ToString() is a function. try this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 299; i++)
    {
        stringcount += 1;
        ButtonStrings.Add(stringcount.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice way of doing it:

```cs
var buttonStrings = Enumerable.Range(1, 300).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```